# In BTTF2 is the rest of the USA in a state of anarchy?

Tags: back-to-the-future-ii

The alternate 1985 in *Back to the Future Part II* shows Hill Valley pretty much in a state of anarchy; drive-by shootings and home invasions seem common place, burned out cars and marauding gangs everywhere etc. This is caused by Biff’s meddling with the timeline and him becoming a rich autocrat.

But how far did his influence extend? If the rest of the country was “normal” it seems strange that the state and federal authorities would allow this situation to persist.

Comment: Just look at places like modern day Camden or Detroit. The authorities kind of give up because it is not worth their lives and/or each individual crime is not enough to warrant federal involvement.

Comment: On the local level... "Kid, I own the police!"

Comment: @Skooba I don’t think they’re quite as bad as the Hill Valley depicted in the film.

Comment: no it's much sadder than that. Hill Valley at least has a casino.

Comment: Portland seems a good example of lawlessness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If memory serves, the only real information we have outside of Hill Valley is from the newspaper showing Doc Brown being committed:

[image: the newspaper showing Doc Brown being committed]

As you can see, in 1985, Richard Nixon is in his fourth term, seeking a fifth, and has kept the Vietnam War going ten years longer than it lasted in the normal timeline.

Comment: Ahem; https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2013/01/back-to-the-futures-terrible-newspaper.html